# How to reconstruct Binary Tree from path encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, path, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have inputs of the following form:

(11,LL) (7,LLL) (8,R) (5,) (4,L) (13,RL) (2,LLR) (1,RRR) (4,RR) ()

whereby the second field indicates the path from the root node, and empty field indicates the root node and () indicates the end of data.

The output would be
levelorder:5 4 8 11 13 4 7 2 1

How can I reconstruct the binary tree? Note that there is a possibility that there might be a possibility that a node is missing. For example, LLL and L are present, but no node is connecting them, for such a case, a node of value -1 should be created to connect them.

What I've figured out so far is creating a NodePath class which stores the data and the path e.g. NodePath(11,LL) both of string value. Next, I iterate through every string token. During the iteration, I compare the path lengths and store them in a LinkedList. 
E.g. 11,LL --> 7,LLL and when 8 comes then it becomes 8,R --> 11,LL --> 7,LLL

Now, this is where I'm stuck because I don't know how to differentiate the LLL and the LLR and how to construct a binary tree accordingly. I'm afraid I would put LLL and LLR in opposite positions.

Comment: Do you already have an object to model a tree node?

Comment: Homework? At least show the expected result. Interesting certainly.

Comment: Well, insert any missing nodes on your way to the node you are inserting. Auto-inserted nodes get the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `Map` with key-value pairs - keys are your paths ("LLL") and values the numbers ("7").

In a second step iterate over `Map`'s EntrySet and build each path top-down, creating new nodes with default value "-1" where there aren't any and using existent node when possible.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting problem. I would suggest giving tree nodes the capability of following a path constructing nodes as they go. I'll ignore all the code for decoding the strings and jump to the heart of construction:

```
class Node {
    public enum Direction {
        L, R;
    }

    private int value = -1;
    private EnumMap<Direction, Node> children = new EnumMap<>(Direction.class);

    public Node nodeWithPath(List<Direction> path) {
        if (path.isEmpty()) {
            return this;
        } else {
            Direction direction = path.remove(0);
            if (!children.containsKey(direction))
                children.put(direction, new Node());
            return children.get(direction).nodeWithPath(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's a simple matter when you decode an instruction of:

```
root.nodeWithPath(path).setValue(value);
```

---

As an additional bit of (possible) help, by using 'L' and 'R' as the enum constants you can create the paths trivially in Java 8 from your string:

```
public void addValue(Node root, String pathString, int value) {
    List<Direction> path = Arrays.stream(pathString.toCharArray())
        .map(Character::toString)
        .map(Node.Direction::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    root.nodeWithPath(path).setValue(value);
}
```

However if you are early on in the process of learning Java then the code I've just written may be more confusing than helpful so feel free to ignore it and use traditional iteration or parsing via tokenisation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on [grappa](https://github.com/fge/grappa).

First, the basic class for a node:

```
public final class BinaryTreeNode
{
    private int value = -1;
    private BinaryTreeNode left = null;
    private BinaryTreeNode right = null;

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getRight()
    {
        return right;
    }

    public void setValue(final int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setLeft(final BinaryTreeNode left)
    {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public void setRight(final BinaryTreeNode right)
    {
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Now the builder class:

```
public final class BinaryTreeBuilder
{
    private final BinaryTreeNode root = new BinaryTreeNode();

    private BinaryTreeNode current = root;

    private int nodeValue;

    public BinaryTreeNode getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public boolean setValue(final String match)
    {
        nodeValue = Integer.parseInt(match);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean moveLeft()
    {
        BinaryTreeNode node = current.getLeft();
        if (left == null) {
            node = new BinaryTreeNode();
            current.setLeft(node);
        }
        current = node;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean moveRight()
    {
        BinaryTreeNode node = current.getRight();
        if (right == null) {
            node = new BinaryTreeNode();
            current.setRight(node);
        }
        current = node;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean commitNode()
    {
        current.setValue(nodeValue);
        current = root;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally the parser:

```
public class BinaryTreeParser
    extends BaseParser<BinaryTreeNode>
{
    protected final BinaryTreeBuilder = new BinaryTreeBuilder();

    Rule endOfData()
    {
        return sequence("()", EOI);
    }

    Rule moves()
    {
        return firstOf(
            sequence('L', builder.moveLeft()),
            sequence('R', builder.moveRight())
        );
    }

    Rule oneNode()
    {
        return sequence(
            '(',
            sequence(oneOrMore(digit()), builder.setValue(match())),
            ',',
            zeroOrMore(moves()),
            ')', builder.commitNode();
        );
    }

    Rule allNodes()
    {
        return join(sequence(testNot(endOfData()), oneNode())
            .using(' ')
            .min(0);
    }

    public Rule fullTree()
    {
        return sequence(allNodes(), endOfData(), push(builder.getRoot());
    }
}
```

Now you just have to run the parser and collect the result:

```
final BinaryTreeParser parser = Parboiled.createParser(BinaryTreeParser.class);

final ParseRunner<BinaryTreeNode> runner = new BasicParseRunner<>(parser.fullTree());

final ParsingResult<BinaryTreeNode> result = runner.run(yourInput);

if (result.isSuccess())
    tree = result.getTopStackValue();
```

Since grappa depends on Guava and Guave provides a [`BinaryTreeTraverser`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BinaryTreeTraverser.html), you would then use that to display the result.

Of course, this approach is rather "sophisticated"; here is a more simple one:

- create a `Comparator<String>` which compares as follows: a string is greater than another if it is longer; and if they are of equal length, then canonical ordering applies;
- create a `TreeMap<String, Integer>` with the paths as keys, node values as values, and your comparator above as a key comparator;
- parse your nodes into the map;
- display entries in order.

Note however that you'll need to check before display that you do have an entry for the root, ie the empty string.